# How should I store multiple users in a database when they all have different roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a property viewing app with four users: Office Manager, Property Advisor, Seller and Buyer. I would prefer to have one login for all but I don't know where I should start.

I need to have their Id's as I am using them for different functions in the application. Example a sellerId would be linked to a property. A buyerId, and PropertyAdvisorId would be linked to an appointment. I was wondering what the best approach for this would be?

Comment: Have a single user table with user data, then if each user can only have one role, just have a ROLEID in the user table and it references a Role table.  If a user can have more then one role, have a UserRole table that has UserID  and RoleID  this could be a one to many relationship, where one UserID in user table, but many in UserRole table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean you really have four users, or four types of users? I assume the latter.

### Inherited Users

If your types have a lot in common, like Name, Address, etc, it would be best to have a base type `User`, and several derived types: `OfficeManager`, `PropertyAdvisor`, etc.

Every `User` has zero or more `Rights`, every `Right` is acknowledged to zero or more `Users`: a simple many-to-many relationship.

Databases don't handle the concept of inheritance very well, you'll have to use a work-around to implement it. Entity framework knows several strategies to implement inheritance. [Several of them are described here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

In your case the [Table-Per-Type](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) would be the best: You'll have one `Users` table, and separate tables for the derived classes: a `Sellers` table, a `Buyers` table etc. Each of these tables will have the foreign key to the `User` table.

```
abstract class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every User has zero or more rights (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Right> Rights {get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}

class Seller : User
{
    // inherit primary key Id from base class
    ... // seller properties
}
class Buyer : User
{
    // inherit primary key Id from base class
    ... // buyer properties
}

class Rights
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every right is acknowledged to zero or more Users (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get; set;}

    ... // properties that handle the rights.
}
```

You'll need to tell Entity Framework that you want separate tables for Users / Buyers / Sellers. This can be done using Attributes. I prefer using fluent API:

```
public MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    // The tables:
    public DbSet<Right> Rights {get; set;}
    public DbSet<User> Users {get; set;
    public DbSet<Seller> Sellers {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Buyer> Buyers {get; set;}
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Buyers and Sellers are in separate tables:
        modelBuilder.Entity<Buyer>().ToTable("Buyers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Seller>().ToTable("Sellers");

        // if you want you could name the User and Right tables
        // but that is not needed. Entity Framework already knows
        // they should be in separate tables
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
    }
}
```

This will lead to a `Users` table, a `Rights` table, a junction table for the many-to-many relation between `Users` and `Rights`, and one separate table per user derived class, each with a foreign key to the `Users` table.

Did you notice that I made the User class abstract? This is to prevent users of the `DbContext` to Add a `User`. We don't know `Users` as object, we only know `Buyers` and `Sellers` (etc)

The nice thing about Table Per Type is that if you want to query items that all `Users` have, like a Name / Address, only one table is queried, no joins are needed, even if some of these `Users` are `Buyers` and some are `Sellers`. Also, if you only query `Buyer` properties, only the Buyer table is accessed.

The disadvantage is that if you want to query Buyer properties together with its User properties, a Join between the Users and the Buyer table is needed.

Whether Table-Per-Type is the best for you depends on the kind of queries you'll do most. [Read all three described methods](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

### Composition method

Another method would be not to use inheritance, but composition. This way your DbSet classes will better describe your tables. The disadvantage is that it seems a bit strange for users of your DbContext: `Buyers` dont't HAVE `Users`, they ARE `Users`, aren't they?

Instead of saying that an Sellers and Buyers **ARE** special types of Users (inheritance) , you could say that they **HAVE** `UserInformation` (composition). This is a one-to-one relation. Every `UserInformation` has zero or more Rights (one-to-many).

Composition will lead to the same tables as table-per-type. The only difference is that your classes represent your tables better, at the cost of that your classes represent your gut-feeling about `Sellers` and `Buyers` being Users less.

```
class UserInformation
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string FirstName {get; set;}
     public string MiddleName {get; set;}
     ...

     // every UserInformation has zero or more rights: (many-to-many)
     public virtual ICollection<Right> Rights {get; set;}
}
class Buyer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // Every Buyer has some UserInformation using foreign key (one-to-one)
    public int UserInformationId {get; set;}
    public virtual UserInformation UserInformation {get; set;}
    ...
}
class Seller
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // Every Seller has some UserInformation using foreign key (one-to-one)
    public int UserInformationId {get; set;}
    public virtual UserInformation UserInformation {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

This will lead to a `UserInformations` table, a `Rights` table, a junction table for the many-to-many relation between `UserInformations` and `Rights`, and one separate table per user derived class, each with a foreign key to the `Users` table. Exactly the same tables.

> The choice is yours: use inheritance if you want to hide the internal database structure to the users of your `DbContext`, use composition if you want to let your database design seep through to the DbContext users.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Is there anyway to incorporate this with the asp identity? Is there any other resources you could point me to? Again thank you so much.